# How to find pixel density in LED Display Board?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, power-engineering, current

How to find pixel density in LED Display Board?
How do we compare pixel per inch and dots per inch?

In this example, a screen of 16'x9' is shown. How did they calculate 4875x2710P and 975x548p and so on. I know that they are adding more pixels for higher image resolution. I am very confused as I am not able to calculate it. I am attaching screenshot.

[image]

Comment: pixel density is literally number of pixels divided by distance

Answer (score 1):

- 4875 pixels at 1 mm pitch gives a screen width of 4875 mm = 4.875 m = 15.99 feet (16 feet).
- 975 pixels at 5 mm pitch is also 4875 mm.
- 244 pixels at 20 mm pitch is 4880 mm so it's almost the same.

> How did they calculate 4875x2710P and 975x548p and so on.

They didn't. That's given in the datasheet. It's the count of the physical pixels on the display or projector.

> How do we compare pixel per inch and dots per inch?

1 pixel = 1 dot. ('pixel' comes from "PICture ELement" with an X instead of a C.)